# Ajax get me cambia el protocolo de http a https

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Quizás la pregunta sea básica, pero no estoy encontrando el porqué.

Estoy intentando hacer una llamada get mediante jquery ajax, la URL tiene el protocolo HTTP pero cuando hago click al botón que ejecuta la llamada, me cambia el protocolo a HTTPS.

¿Hay forma de prevenir esto?

Comment: Intenta abrir esa URL desde el navegador a ver si también te la cambia.  Si es así entonces no puedes hacer nada, pues eso indica que es el servidor destino que tiene la instrucción de cambiarla, ya sea mediante .htaccess u otros métodos. En este caso lo que tendrías que hacer es cambiar tu la llamada ajax a https y vendria a ser lo mismo seguramente--- ¿o que problema tienes al hacerlo?

Comment: De hecho, es posible que el navegador "recuerde" ese dominio y ya ni siquiera espere a que le redirijan: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security